# How can I have threads report back when done, VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

I need a few threads working simultaneously with URL requests in a VB.NET 2010 app. Once one of them finishes, it should continue with the next task in a list.

I'm new to using threads. Since it seems like I can't declare an array of `BackgroundWorker`, I thought I'd have a control class that creates an instance of a task class for each task, which in turn starts a `BackgroundWorker` in its constructor.
However, with this approach I'm not sure how to report the result back to the control class upon completion. I had this vague idea that I could send a reference to an object in the control class (or to a public event I can trigger, is this possible?), but then I have to somehow store this address until the work is done. And I don't know how I can store the address from a ByRef for future use.

What I would basically like to know is: What is the standard pattern for accomplishing this, how should I think, can anyone point to an example?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since it seems like I can't declare an array of `BackgroundWorker`

You *can*. And in you case, it looks like you absolutely should, since the `BackgroundWorker` offers exactly the functionality you need.

Just declare the worker in code, rather than via the Forms Designer: The Forms Designer doesn’t support arrays of controls/components. But in code, no such restriction exists. The only problem is that you cannot declare lists/arrays/… as `WithEvents`. You need to register and deregister event handlers manually on all instances, using [`AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx).

Comment: Yes it told me "'WithEvents' variables cannot be typed as arrays." when I tried. Manual handlers is another things I'll be doing for the first time, interesting! Thanks, just what I needed.